# ElasticSearch - why ScriptDocValues returns unique values?

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, groovy, scripting

I have simple mapping - one `string` field and one `string[]` field.
The array of strings contains duplicate values, and I get those duplicate values in query:

```
{ "query" : { "term" : {"id" : "579a252585b8c5c428fa0a3c"} } }
```

Returns a single valid hit:

```
{
  "id" : "579a252585b8c5c428fa0a3c",
  "touches" : [ "5639abfb5cba47087e8b4571", "5639abfb5cba47087e8b4571", "5639abfb5cba47087e8b4571", "5639abfb5cba47087e8b457b", "5639abfb5cba47087e8b457b" 
}
```

But in metric script aggregation:

```
 "aggs": {
    "path": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "map_script": "_agg['result'] = doc['touches'].values"
      }
    }
  }
```

retuns

```
 "aggregations" : {
    "path" : {
      "value" : [ { }, {
        "result" : [ "5639abfb5cba47087e8b4571", "5639abfb5cba47087e8b457b" ]
      }, { }, { }, { } ]
    }
  }
```

that element is `org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Strings`, casting it `toString()` returns a json-encoded 2-element array.

### So, the question:

Why does `ScriptDocValues$Strings` return only unique array values and how to get the initial array in script aggregation?

Thanks.

### UPD

I found that for numerical values (in particular floats) everything works perfect.